# How to return the middle word before and after the certain words

Tags: php, string

```
$string = 'LifeSteal V \n';
```

I want the function to return `V` when I send `LifeSteal` and `\n` to a function.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: and clarify what the function should return if at least one of the given string is not found

Comment: What did you try so far?

Answer (score 0):

If the parts to remove are always the same you can use `str_replace()` function passing as serach value an array with both parts you want to remove

```
function remove_strings($string) {
    return str_replace(array('LifeSteal ', ' \n'), '', $string);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try below code :

```
function getStringBetween($string, $start, $end)
{
    $string = ' ' . $string;
    $ini = strpos($string, $start);
    if ($ini == 0) return '';
    $ini += strlen($start);
    $len = strpos($string, $end, $ini) - $ini;
    return substr($string, $ini, $len);
}

$fullstring = 'LifeSteal V \n';
$parsed = getStringBetween($fullstring, 'LifeSteal', '\n');

echo $parsed;
```